# alternating bilinear form with wedge product

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\phi : \textbf{R}^4 \otimes \textbf{R}^4 \rightarrow \textbf{R}$ be an alternating bilinear form.

Prove that there exist linear maps $\alpha, \beta :\textbf{R}^4 \otimes \textbf{R}^4 \rightarrow \textbf{R}$ with $\phi = \alpha \wedge \beta$ if and only if $\phi \wedge \phi = 0$

---

Can somebody help me solving this one?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean to say "there exist linear maps $\alpha,\beta:\textbf{R}^4 \rightarrow \textbf{R}$"?

Comment: Dear @rVitale, I really like your avatar! And you are right about what crystaliza means (or should mean...) .